# Why won't this PC power supply run my BLDC?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, brushless-dc-motor

I would like to power my Arduino and BLDC to be powered with an old computer power supply. My Arduino needs 5V and my 3 phase BLDC needs 12V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEKskg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Details**

- I'm using a SLA5068 N-channel MOSTFET bridge. [Datasheet Here](http://www.semicon.sanken-ele.co.jp/sk_content/sla5068_ds_en.pdf).
- My sequence is taken from the library AccelStepper--[here is the homepage](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper/). The sequence has 3 steps; during each step, only one phase will be on.
- The BLDC motor I'm using is one from an old Western Digital 500gb HDD. I can't find the specs for it, but I know it's rated for 12V because I looked up a datasheet for the motor controller chip that was on the board with it.

The power supply I'm using:
[image]

**Behaviour**

- If I use the 5V for powering my BLDC, it works just fine (except I can't go very fast).
- If I use the 12V supply, it works for a moment and then shuts off.

**Things I've tried**

- Putting a 1K resistor from the 12V to ground. *Also tried with a 570 ohm*
- Putting in a capacitor to ground.
- Putting a fan from the 5V to ground so it has a constant load.
- Putting a flyback diode in the circuit.

**The most puzzling thing**

This works fine with my computer fan, which is a BLDC that has a controller circuit built inside it; this leads me to believe I am missing something in my design.

*Perhaps this is an important detail*, when I use the 5V supply for my 3 phase BLDC, I don't hear any clicking, but when I use the 12V supply, I hear a lot of clicking and then it shuts down quite promptly.

Comment: Can we have an actual schematic please - how are you driving your MOSFET gates?, what type of MOSFET are they? How is the motor wired up (schematic!). How are you commutating the motor? Is your sequencing correct.

Comment: Sure, will do!!

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Maybe you have not met the minimum load for the power supply so it doesn't fully come on?

Comment: Does the supply shut off? (measure with a multimeter) or is it just the motor stalling? If you are not sequencing it correctly (because you are using an open-loop approach), it will likely just stall out because to rotor gets out of sync with the sequencing of the windings.

Comment: Chances are you are putting too much current through it, especially if you leave windings on long enough for the inductance (and any back EMF) to get out of the way.  More critically, it's not clear you can drive the motor (at least with useful torque) by treating it like a sort of 3-wire unipolar stepper motor.  Normally, you would use **bidirectional** drive of the leads, with three half bridges.  You mention a "bridge" but what you have drawn is a simply unipolar low-side switch for each winding.  How many wires come off your motor anyway?

Comment: The power supply shuts off. I am sure the sequencing is correct because I can run the motor up to 5400 rpm with a different power supply.

Comment: @Daniel The BLDC works fine with the 5V supply, and I also have my Arduino powered with the 5V supply.

Comment: Your circuit diagram is wrong.  Either you are using only part of the SLA5068, or else you have failed to draw what you are actually doing.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've done some prior tests using a professional power supply and limiting the current to 3.2amps (I get up to about 8V) and it works very well for my purpose. I've tried the bidirectional approach, but I was getting too much heat being produced with the BJTs I was using. Also, you're correct, I'm not using it as a bridge; I said bridge because that's what SLA5068 component is.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am only using part of the SLA5068. I got it from an electrical tech from my school so it was a freebie :P.

Comment: The solution was to use a large capacitor across the feeds of the power supply and it smoothed out the current draw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.

**CLUES**

1. There would be a clicking noise when I was using the 12V output and it would run for a moment before shutting down.

   - This hinted that the power draw was not constant.
2. My BLDC would run when connected to the 5V output and there were no clicking noises.

   - This hinted that the problem was to do with the amount of current being drawn.
3. The power supply would stay off until I hit the switch off and then back on.

   - This hinted that it was due to a safety feature since it entered a mode where functionality was ceased completely until I restarted the supply.

**Solution**

One of these:
[image]

A large *capacitor* connected from the positive to the negative feed of the power supply smoothed out the sudden changes in current draw and fixed the problem.

Now there is no clicking noise and the motor runs just perfectly.

I hope this helped someone else.

Comment: you sort of need a freewheel diode

Comment: It's built into the MOSFET I'm using.

Comment: If the cct is exactly as you drew it... The intrinsic diode will not provide a freewheel path for the inductive current at forced commutation